# OpenCV: Multiprocessing/threading to process an image while another is captured

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing, multiprocessing

I have an application where I need to take a picture every second for about ten minutes. That gives me 600 pictures. I need to perform some thresholding based tracking and return coordinates for every image. I have the following two functions. One for capturing the images and the other for processing. At present, I capture all images and then pass it to the other function. It works but I know this is not the memory efficient or even an efficient way to do it.

> capture() function ->returns img (img = [1600,1200,3,599])
>
> *img has 600 images stored and the foo() function processes them after capture() is done.*
>
> foo() returns an array of size (1L,1L,600L) =>(x,y) coordinates for each of the image.

I would like the second function to run after the first image is captured (while it is capturing the second image) and so on. This way only two images will be requiring memory - image being captured by capture(), image being processed by foo(). I looked into 'multiprocessing' and 'threading' posts and documentation. I don't quite understand how to sync or time it, as i want the first function to work after one second, every time without delay. Thank you in advance guys!

Comment: Usually, one second is long enough for heavy processing of an image, so you should have enough time to acquire and process in the same loop.

Comment: You are right. I tried but it did not work very well. It is probably because of the camera I use - not a very good one in terms of speed. I mean, without a delay of at least 0.5 seconds after VideoCapture(), I will just get a black image. I set the resolution, exposure, etc. and I am assuming that the camera takes its time to change its setting . I can change the camera, but I was wondering if I could make use of multiprocessing to fix this.

Comment: What are you doing during these 0.5 seconds ? You could be processing. And a camera needing that long to adjust settings is a little hard to swallow.

Comment: True, I have to get a new one. And I don'd do anything in that 0.5 seconds and that's my problem. I use time.sleep(), a blocking function.

Comment: Your best bet is to read up on OpenMP. you could start two threads, the first one captures images, and adds a task to the task queue. The second thread processes tasks on the queue. Given your 1s, you don't need to worry too much about synchronization, thread 2 would be finished by the time thread 1 puts another job on the queue. So you'd need just two buffers that you alternate (read into one, enqueue it for processing, read into the second buffer, enqueue that one, read into the first buffer again, ...)

Comment: @Manoj: as a simple solution, you can replace that sleep by the processing of the previous image + a sleep for the remaining time. Double buffering will be enough.

Comment: @CrisLuengo... Sure.. will work on it!

Comment: @YvesDaoust I did not do that because the very first image would not be available for the process function. But I can work around it. I could not believe I didn't give this a shot! Thank you!

Comment: @Manoj: anyway, I guess that it is worth to investigate why there is this acquisition delay.